# DependencyResolver.SetResolver Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I'm trying to set the container on a new app using the `Dependency.SetResolver` method and using autofac with autofac mvc 5 integration.

The problem is that setting the resolver doesn't appear to do anything. The default resolver will always be used and will always expect a default constructor.

Any ideas?

Edit - The `global.asax.cs`, I've simplified it down to:

```
var b = new ContainerBuilder();  
b.RegisterType<UserInfo>().As<IUserSession>().InstancePerHttpRequest();  
var container = b.Build();  
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

And `HomeController` takes an `IUserSession` in its constructor. The exception thrown is "`No parameterless constructor defined for this object." Thrown from "System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create"`

Comment: Please post your code where you calling `Dependency.SetResolver`! Also your container configuration, your controller's constructor, and the exception message!

Comment: Is the `SetResolver` call throwing the exception or is it when the controller is getting resolved? If you debug into the program and figure out what `DependencyResolver.Current` is, is it the default resolver or the `AutofacDependencyResolver`? (I have a feeling the title of the question is wrong - I think the resolution is failing, not the `SetResolver` call.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You forgot to register your controllers:

```
b.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
```

More info on Autofac [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration)

Comment: The original version had this in there, but it was this.GetType().Assembly. The problem being that the global.asax gets compiled to a different assembly.

Comment: @flukus Then it's better to use a controller class, like this: b.RegisterControllers(typeof(MyController).Assembly);

Comment: To use the RegisterControllers() you will need to add a using statement for Autofac.Integration.Mvc;

Comment: Where else do we need to make entries or do registration for Autofac to work. Because I've implemented the code exactly it is given in the documentation of Autofac. Here is my `IocConfig` file: [IocConfig](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Oey039)

Comment: @barnes You need to include all assemblies where you store your controllers.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please be more elaborate. I don't fully understand your reply. What assemblies you are talking about in particular? According to [Autofac-Docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#quick-start), it says to include `MvcApplication` class which is in `Global.asax`. What else I must include here?

Comment: @barnes Autofac has `ContainerBuilder.RegisterControllers()` method that takes `Assembly` as an input parameter. Then Autofac scans the assembly you provided for `Controller` classes using reflection and registers them automatically for you. So that if you store controller in separate assemblies you need to specify them all.

Comment: I have just started a sample project to implement `Autofac`. There are only 2 controllers and nothing else. I am not sure what is going wrong, but I will keep searching. Thanks for your help and time. :)

Comment: My projects `web.config` contains runtime assembly binding for `Microsoft.Owin` only. While the other project that is running using the autofac contains bindings for `Web.Grease`, `Autofac`, `Newtonsoft.Json` etc. Do I need to add these run-time assembly binding manually or they get generated automatically?