# Exception in Autofac : No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, autofac

Here is my class where dependencies are resolved

```
namespace TestProj
{
    public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            SetAutofacWebAPI();
        }

        private static void SetAutofacWebAPI()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<Encryption>().As<IEncryption>().InstancePerRequest();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder.Build()));
        }
    }
}
```

*In the Global.asax, I have this : `Bootstrapper.Run();`*

---

**Here is my UserService class:**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IEncryption _Encryption;

    public UserService(Encryption Encryption)
    {
        _Encryption = Encryption;
    }
    //Rest of the service here
}
```

the `Encryption` class is a similar one.

---

**And the controller is here :**

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService _UserService;
    public AccountController(UserService UserService)
    {
        _UserService = UserService;
    }

    public JsonResult GetLoginLogs(int Id)
    {
        var Logs = _UserService.GetLoginLogById(Id);
        return Json(Logs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    //The rest of the controller
}
```

---

**here is the version info:**

```
Autofac : 3.5.2
MVC : 4.0.40804.0
DOTNET : 4
```

And then, when try `localhost:5000/Account/GetLoginLogs/1` this exception comes up:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Someone please help. I am in seriously in trouble!

Comment: I think you are confusing how to explicitly inject into the classes. use the interfaces instead of the concrete classes when injecting into the dependent classes

Comment: You registered `UserService` as `IUserService`.  You also failed to register your MVC controllers.

Comment: Check, the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925290/dependencyresolver-setresolver-not-working), on same lines as Amy above

Comment: thanks @Amy Your comment was so helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing how you registered the dependencies.

Update from comments by @Amy:

> You also failed to register your MVC controllers

```
// You can register controllers all at once using assembly scanning...
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Source: [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#register-controllers)

Also use the interfaces instead of the concrete classes when explicitly  injecting into the dependent classes as that is what you registered with the container.

```
public class UserService : IUserService {
    private readonly IEncryption _Encryption;

    public UserService(IEncryption Encryption) {
        _Encryption = Encryption;
    }
    //Rest of the service here
}

public class UserController : Controller {
    private readonly IUserService _UserService;

    public AccountController(IUserService UserService) {
        _UserService = UserService;
    }

    public JsonResult GetLoginLogs(int Id) {
        var Logs = _UserService.GetLoginLogById(Id);
        return Json(Logs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    //The rest of the controller
}
```

Comment: @PrashanthBenny That is a standard misleading error that the framework throws when it cannot initialize the controller. I agree it is a weird error message.

Comment: That's great help Nkosi. Anyway, it's late night In my place. Let me try your solution tomorrow!

Comment: It looks like you use MVC, not Web API (controller inherits from `Controller`, not `ApiController`), so you should register your controllers with `builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`, not `builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`.

Comment: @tdragon you are correct. I copied it from documentation and overlooked that detail. thanks. will update.

Comment: Thank you so much... all of you! you save my life this time :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I believe the exception you get is not misleading if you get deeper into it and analyze the exception message and stack trace. You would find exactly which service could not be found and created by the container - in this case it would be `UserService` in `AccountController` (and later, `Encryption` in `UserService` as well). The exception with "no parameterless contructor found" simply says that in existing contructor with parameters there is one or more parameters which cannot be resolved by the container, and, because the parameterless constructor is missing, required type cannot be created.

It can also mean you forgot to register your controllers in the container, so the Autofac has no idea it should inject any dependecies into the controllers.

Going further - Autofac is very explicit with the registrations - you can only inject/resolve what you registered at the start up of the application.
If you simply use `builder.RegisterType<UserService>()` - without any `As<>` you can only inject `UserService` directly. But when you add `.As<>`: `builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>()`, you cannot inject `UserService` anymore, but `IUserService`. To keep the possibility to inject `UserService` you would have to use `AsSelf()`: `builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().AsSelf()`. Then, you can inject both `IUserService` and `UserService`. Keep in mind Autofac registration API is fluent, you can amend as many `As<>` as you want.

In Dependecy Injection world we do not like tidly coupled components, so injecting concrete classes, instead of interfaces - like you did - is not recommended - you should use interfaces wherever it is possible. So your registrations are correct, but you should inject `IUserService` instead of `UserService` and `IEncryption` instead of `Encryption` in your components.
It would ease potential unit testing of these components, allowing you mocking up dependencies easily.

Also, you should register your controllers as well:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())‌​;
```

Comment: I just copied the style from nopcommerce project of using the constructor injection.